# How to filter a dataset rows using variables

Tags: apache-spark

I try to filter rows of a dataset using variables like so :

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = dF.select(dF.col("*")).filter(col(list.get(0)) == lit(list.get(1))));
```

But i get a compilation error :

> Cannot resolve filter(boolean)

What's the solution to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter takes column instead of boolean as parameter. So to compare columns you should use `equalTo` method that will return a column instead of `==`:

```java
Dataset<Row> dataset = dF.select(dF.col("*")).filter(col(list.get(0)).equalTo(lit(list.get(1)))));
```